# devise_token_auth:install in a rails app does not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to start a project with [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) with the instructions of `README.md` file.
When i run `rails g devise_token_auth:install User auth` the console becomes locked and does not display any messages.

To create my project i followed these steps:

```
rails new foo
cd foo
bundle install

#then i add the gem 'devise_token_auth' to my Gemfile and after
bundle install

#now the problem...
rails g devise_token_auth:install User auth
#the console becomes locked with no messages
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS, ruby-2.2.1 and my Gemfile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'pg'
gem 'spring', group: :development

gem 'devise_token_auth'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the paths to the generated files are writable..

Comment: @errata thank you for the tip. The path was not writable and i didn't see that :/ my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @errata

The problem was in my folder, which was not writable.
I just change the folder permissions and now it works.